# Warscore drops when I win

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I noticed something strange today. Immediately after I successfully assaulted a holding, my warscore **dropped** about 10 percentage points. I figured it may had something to do with my losses, so I reloaded and just let the siege wait it out untill I won — however, the result was still the same. Shouldn't I **earn** warscore for kicking ass?

Secondly, I think in EU3, you would gain much more warscore for capturing capitals. Is this still the case? I've read that you get 75% more warscore for holding all your objective wargoals.

As a bonus question, what do you find is the usual point at which an enemy accepts defeat? I heard a warscore of 80% is a good rule of thumb, but I've had a warscore of 97% and the enemy was still extremely reluctant (four minuses) and though "things are going my way", even though I had held a lot of his holdings for five years and won every single battle.

Comment: In the war stats screen, the warscore is also displayed as numbers, often in the thousands to hundreds-of-thousands range, and each thing that contributes to the warscore will have a similar number (or at least a percentage). When you saw the warscore percentage change, how did the hard numbers change, and were there any new contributing events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured it out. I could choose between three different casus belli – infidel, one county and a whole duchy. I chose the latter, since that duchy was Castille, and I had a claim to the defunct throne.

Castille has four counties, and I held three of them. The last was held by rebels, and I figured I wouldn't waste my forces on them, so I besieged his other counties instead.

It seems the warscore dropped, because I did not have a valid CB outside Castille. When I turned my forces around and defeated the rebels, I could press for victory almost immediately.

Comment: If you don't successfully siege the target area, you will start slowly losing warscore over time (when you over over the score in the war screen, it will say “(the opponent) controls Castille”). But it shouldn't cause sudden 10% drops.

Comment: I had sieged three counties (which I had CB to) – if I waited, the war score would slowly increase even to 98% and the enemy still wouldn't budge. When I successfully took a county other than those four I had declared war over, the war score immediately dropped ~10%. I tested this several times, with the exact same result. When I successfully sieged the last county, the war score instantly increased to 98%, and further to 100% after only a day or two.